# How to copy tables using Azure Data Factory, without manual selection, preserving their names

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to backup existing table storage 1:1 to new table storage. Be default I have to manually select tables, and on next page I have to manually set the name to existing one. How to make it automatic? See the screenshots:

- Event if `Select all` is ticked, if new table appears later, it won't be included [image: Tables selection]
- Every table has a `TableX` name, I want them to have the same names like in source [image: Table rename]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a event trigger for table storage that when an new table created.

I would suggest you still use `Select all` option. Then create a [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#schedule-trigger) to run the pipeline. That's a way to 'sync' the data between Table Storage 1 and 2. If your Table Storage is not very large, it could be a good way.

HTH.

Comment: I suppose `USE QUERY` may have possibility to return all tables, but I don't know how to construct such a query.

Comment: Hi @user963935, Select all surely means choose all the tables, it actually use a foreach active to loop the tables and copy them it another table storage. You want to construct a query to filter all the tables, that should be another question.

Comment: Yes, `Select all` returns all tables, but I want to run this script every day as backup, so tables created after script creation won't be included.

Comment: You want use query to select the all exist tables, except the new table? Don't you think it's same with manually select the exist table? Why do you insist to use query script? In addition, that's out of your original question, I suggestion you post a new question. Others could give you more helps, Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user963935 do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I think I need to create another thread and delete this one...

Comment: @user963935, My brother, you don't need to do that and just keep this one. They are different questions. We all glad to help you.  Can you  accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. If others can give better solutions(you think so), you also can unmark mine and accept it.